# Is this a valid way to take a list of digit characters and use them to create a long integer?

Tags: c++, list, operators, operator-overloading, long-integer

Is this a valid way to take a list of digit characters and use them to create a long integer?

```
LongInt operator+(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y)
{
    int xCount = 1;
    long int xValue = 0;
    list<char>::iterator it;

    //x.val is a list<char> that contains the digits needed to create the long int
    for(it = x.val.begin(); it != x.val.end(); it++)
    {
        xValue = xValue + (*it - '0');
        xCount++;
    }
}
```

The purpose of xCount is to keep track of the type of number it is (1's, 10's, 100's, 1000's, etc).

LongInt is a custom class which has a list called val.  This method is supposed to take the two LongInt objects, convert their list to Long Ints, then add them together.  I know I'm missing the code for the y object but I wanted to make sure I have the x down before I try for y.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and I explained how to do it in your previous thread, except that I was wrong with the reverse iterator. You have to start from the beginning not the end. Sorry about that confusion.. This should be enough:

```
   list<char> digits;
   digits.push_back('1');
   digits.push_back('2');
   digits.push_back('3');

   long int xValue = 0;
   list<char>::iterator it;

   for(it = digits.begin(); it != digits.end(); it++)
   {
      xValue = xValue * 10 + (*it - '0');
   }
```

Let's say the list is {'1','2', '3'}. Initially xvalue is 0, then it becomes 0*10+1, which is 1. Then it 1*10 + 2 = 12. Last 12 * 10 + 3 = 123.

Comment: I like it, although this could screw you if you pass in 'X' as one of the characters. (I'm assuming validation of the input is left as an exercise to the reader? :-) Also might be worth taking into consideration the `-` sign.

Comment: yes, OK, that "enough" part in my answer is misleading. I was referring only to simplify the loop body. of course one should do some validation there and as you said, perhaps include the sign too.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question, however I get an error in the for loop with the " = " saying that, "No operator "=" matches these operands.  Any idea as to why that is?

Comment: well, at which line the error is? and what is x.val? the code that I've shown works very well. and BTW, in your edited post, you forgot multiplying xValue with 10 before addding (*it - '0').

Answer (score 0):

You need to be taking 10^ to the xCount power, anyway (but you don't increment it anywhere). xCount should probably be the length of your number. The if statement should have `==` and be `if(xCount == 1)`, but you don't need to distinguish that, because you can consider the first digit multiplier as 10^0.

```
"123" = 1*10^2+2*10^1+2*10^0
```

Answer (score 0):

If `LongInt` is a class that can have arbitrary precision, it can't be converted to primitive data type like `long int xValue`.

If you want to add two `LongInt`s, then you've to do it manually. Character by characer. For example, if x = "174", y = "43", then you're program will do the following:

```
carry = 0;

174
 43
  ^---- 4 + 3 + carry = 7, carry = 0

174
 43
 ^----- 7 + 4 + carry = 1, carry = 1

174
 43
^------ 1 + 0 + carry = 2, carry = 0
```

From the algorithm above, the result is "217", which you should store in another `LongInt` and return that.

Comment: How would I set that up? I can't think of a way to loop through the values of each and add them together without having a nested for loop, and that won't work because it would take the first value and add it to all the values in the second number.

Comment: @Ctak: you don't need any nested loop. a linear loop like the one you have now will work. think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something about operator overloading (sp? :-) ? Why not just forget about xCount and just:

```
long xValue = 0;
for(it = x.val.rbegin(); it != x.val.rend(); it++) 
{
  xValue = xValue * 10 + ( *it - '0');
}
```

What does xCount have to do with it?